# How to check for a specific word per line in a text file through C++?

Tags: c++, file, c++11, linked-list, singly-linked-list

> The name and RUID is read from read.txt, if it find a string ‘RUID’ in
>   read.txt, you need to create a new Linkedlist to store the following
>   RUID and name (there  are multiple RUID in the string), finish reading
>   all the elements in read.txt, use operator overloading + to connect
>   linkedlists together

This is what's being asked of me. I already know how to open the text file and have managed to do everything else, including the operator overloading. I'm just confused as to how I should go about trying to get and store the information from the text file into separate linked lists.

This is my pseudo-code (I just don't know how to quite implement it)

```
while (!File.eof())
{
if (a string in a line = RUID)
{
make a new LinkedList and set as current LinkedList
jump to next line
read line into the LinkedList
}
}
```

This is my text file (ignore the spaces in-between each line)

RUID Name

4325 name1

RUID Name

5432 name2

6530 name3

RUID Name

1034 name4

2309 name5

and this is my code thus far

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    LinkedList x;
    string line;
    ifstream ReadFile;
    ReadFile.open("read.txt");
    int counter = 0;
    if (ReadFile.is_open())
    {
        while (!ReadFile.eof())
        {

        }
    }

    ofstream WriteFile("Write.txt");
    if (WriteFile.is_open())
    {
        Node* extra;

        int inf = 9;
        while (inf != 10)
        {
            cout << "Select the following options:" << endl;
            cout << "1. Add node to the list" << endl;
            cout << "2. Remove node from list" << endl;
            cout << "3. Print list" << endl;
            cout << "4. Print element of the list" << endl;
            cout << "5. Sort the list" << endl;
            cout << "6. Quit" << endl;
            int option;
            cin >> option;
            cout << "Selection: " << option << endl;

            if (option == 1)
            {
                cout << "Enter student name: ";
                string insert;
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin, insert);

                int temp = rand() % 9000 + 1000;

                extra = new Node(insert, temp);
                x.addNode(extra);
                cout << endl;
                x.printList();
            }
            else if (option == 2)
            {
                cout << "Enter the RUID to be remove: ";
                int remove;
                cin >> remove;
                cout << endl;

                x.removeNode(remove);
                x.printList();
            }
            else if (option == 3)
            {
                x.printList();
            }
            else if (option == 4)
            {
                cout << "Enter the index: ";
                int index;
                cin >> index;
                cout << endl;

                x.printElement(index);
            }
            else if (option == 5)
            {
                x.sortList();
                x.printList();
            }
            else if (option == 6)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Invalid output" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the "name" always a single word, or can it be multiple words (like a "real" name)?

Comment: Also, you might want to read ["Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Name will always be a single word (in my case)

Comment: Also, after having read that, would me using eof inside of a loop cause problems for me?

Answer (score 0):

Simply read as two strings in a loop. If the first is equal to `"RUID"` do whatever special handling you need to start a new list, else [convert it to an integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) and add to the current list.

Example (including pseudo-code for list handling):

```
ListType* current_list = nullptr;
std::string ruid_string, name;
while (ReadFile >> ruid_string >> name)
{
    if (ruid_string == "RUID")
    {
        // Logic to create a new list or whatever
        if (current_list != nullptr)
        {
            // A list already exists, add it to the "master" list
            master_list.AddSubList(current_list);
        }

        current_list = CreateList();
    }
    else
    {
        int ruid = std::stoi(ruid_string);

        // Add node to current list
        if (current_list != nullptr)
            current_list->AddNode(ruid, name);
    }
}

if (current_list != nullptr)
{
    // Add the last list to the master list
    master_list.AddSubList(current_list);
}
```

Comment: Hmm...but, in the first if statement, that list would only exist for one loop, before I could even use it, no, and the node would have to be added into a list and then THAT list would have to be added to the main list

Comment: @CodingPoding Added some pseudo-code to show how the list(s) can be handled.

Comment: Oh alright, that definitely helps. But what do you mean by current_list = CreateList();

Comment: Like, what would I do there?